# Why is the midrange statistic more skewed than the median or mean?

Tags: bootstrap

I have a dataset and ran the bootstrap. My results are as follows:

[image]

Clearly, the mean of the dataset is stable as the mean is a Gaussian. The median seems to be a bit less defined. However the midrange is very skewed.

Can someone describe why this would be so? Why are the median and midrange not as well defined in bootstrap resampling?

Comment: It's not clear at all that the data are Gaussian and the mean can be stable even if not, given e.g. central limit theorem(s) . But that aside, (min + max)/2, which I take to be midrange, is almost necessarily more sensitive than the mean to skewness. The summary just uses 2 values and either min or max will be usually be responsive to one kind of skewness or another. To see this, consider moving closer to the median , e.g. by working with two extremes in each tail, or with (min + median + max)/3, etc.

Comment: Interesting. Shouldn't they all be Gaussian in theory? Or do I need to collect more data?

Comment: You ask rather short and often challenging questions, but they are also often cryptic. What is the question about? Is it about the analysis of your dataset? We can't see it. Is it about Gaussian distributions? Is it about distributions in general? More data for what purpose? For just about any purpose, (min + max)/2 captures very little about the data, so using a bigger sample won't help; in fact the bigger the sample, the less useful it can be!

Comment: lol, it's just some random dataset I found. Shouldn't the mean, median, and midrange be all gaussian?

Comment: Bootstrapping (min + max)/2 is particularly challenging. Some bootstrap samples will catch precisely the sample min and max but many won't. Note the right-hand mode.

Comment: I am happy with your sense of humour, but you didn't clarify anything with your comment.

Comment: Interesting. That makes sense - if I bootstrapped enough, it should eventually become Gaussian.

Comment: "if I bootstrapped enough, it should eventually become Gaussian": I didn't say that at all.

Comment: Consider bootstrapping the sample maximum as an extreme problem (pun intended). No bootstrap sample will ever return a higher estimate than the observed maximum, but many will return a lower estimate.

Comment: I don't believe your labels.  The most variable of these three statistics is necessarily the midrange, but you are showing the median as being most variable.